# Solr 4.8.1 on Tomcat 7 cant find solrconfig (Ubuntu)

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, solr

I've added a solr.xml file:

```
<Context docBase="/var/www/solr/solr.war" crossContext="true" >
   <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/var/www/<sitename>/search/" override="true" />
</Context>
```

The file /var/www//search/collection1/solrconfig.xml does exist, the owner is tomcat7 and the permissions are 664 and contains a configuration that is working on my mac with the same version of solr.

Catalina log:

```
Jun 02, 2014 4:45:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/<sitename>/solr.xml
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer:null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: collection1
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.recordAndThrow(CoreContainer.java:911)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:568)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:261)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load core configuration for core collection1
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:66)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:554)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading solr config from /var/www/<sitename>/search/collection1/solrconfig.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.readFromResourceLoader(SolrConfig.java:148)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createSolrConfig(ConfigSetService.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:61)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/var/www/demo.custodiansolutions.com/search/collection1/conf'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:362)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:308)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:86)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.readFromResourceLoader(SolrConfig.java:144)
    ... 11 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And you are sure that the `<sitename>` of the `value="/var/www/<sitename>/search/"` is a valid folder name?

Comment: sorry - the <sitename> bit is a slight redaction, the work is for a client. @MahonriMoriancumer - I honestly don't know how to make it more specific? Is there more information I could provide? I can't get Solr to start up inside a tomcat7 server. Other Wars are starting but this one isn't. That's it really. It works on my Mac.